# python3.x - selective arithmetic based on integer flags

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of "Z" and "N" values and am trying to complete simple arithmetic on them (addition and/or subtraction) based on a flag associated with them. For example:

```
Z = 10
N = 10
flag = 2
```

Where a value of 2 for "flag" would lead to:

```
Z += 1
N -= 1
```

In the past, for multiple values of flag (i.e. a list), I have defined functions such as:

```
def(Z,N,flag):
   if flag==0:
      pass
   elif flag==1:
      Z+=2; N-=1
   elif flag==2:
      Z+=1; N-=1
   elif flag==3:
      Z-=2;N-=2
   return(Z,N)
```

However, this can become rather cumbersome if the number of possible flags is large (TONS of if...elif... statements) and the number of Z,N combinations I need to loop through is high. Does anyone know of a better and more efficient way to go about this logic? I have dabbled with creating dictionaries something like `dict={'0':pass; '1': [Z+=2;N-=1],...}` but quickly realized that it wouldn't work....

Comment: `{0: None, 1: (2, -1), 2: (1, -1), ...}`? You can't store statements (`pass`, assignments, ...) in a dictionary, but a dictionary is still the way to go.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh cool. That works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on @jonrsharpe's comment:

```
def apply_operation(Z, N, flag):
    flag_operations = {
        0: None,
        1: (2, -1),
        2: (1, -1),
        3: (2, 2)
    }

    Z += flag_operations[flag][0]
    N += flag_operations[flag][1]

    return (Z, N)

Z = 10
N = 10
flag = 2

Znew, Nnew = apply_operation(Z, N, flag)

print('Z:', Znew, '\tN:', Nnew)
# Z: 11     N: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your flag are running orderly you can use a simple list. It is less readable but more compact.

```
flags_op = [[0, 0], [2, -1], [1, -1], [2, 2]]
z, n = map(add, [z, n], flags_op[flag])
```